# How to set a PopupMenu text color in menu showed on Button click on Android?

Tags: android, menu, popup

I need to show a pop-up menu below a button in another color than the default color. I was searching on Google but all the results seem to work only in Toolbar or Actionbar overflow menu.

Answer (score 0):

That is called context menu.
Look at the link below
[Custom Popup Menu](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-context-menu-example)